# On Heroku with Rails 5.2, Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)

Tags: heroku, rails-activestorage

When deploying a Rails 5.2.2 app on Heroku, the deploy goes through but if I examine my logs (using `heroku logs`) I get **Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)**

```
2019-06-10T13:00:23.884108+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/aws-sigv4-1.1.0/lib/aws-sigv4/signer.rb:612:in `extract_credentials_provider': Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
2019-06-10T13:00:23.884187+00:00 app[web.1]: missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options:
2019-06-10T13:00:23.884200+00:00 app[web.1]: - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
2019-06-10T13:00:23.884208+00:00 app[web.1]: - :credentials
2019-06-10T13:00:23.884233+00:00 app[web.1]: - :credentials_provider
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are missing the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`, which you should set by environment variable (`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=xxxxxxxx`) where xxxxxxxxx is your master key